# Drupal/ and solr views - how to sort?

Tags: sorting, solr, drupal-7, view

a couple of questions ...

1. How can I sort items from solr index view ?
2. I'd like to set up a flag for nodes I get in that view and I'm wondering if there is any chance to sort by the flag count. Do I need to add a field to store the flagged count and index that too ?

thanks!

---

[klad](http://freeantivirussoftware.info)[rian](http://oh-myzsh.com)